Transit flights for two Schengen countries
I have a Lithuanian tourism Schengen visa and I'm flying from Yerevan to Vilnius, but there are no direct flights, so I should fly to Vienna and from there to Vilnius. But this way Vienna entrance stamp will be in passport and stamp of Vilnius entrance won't be visible as Schengen flights don't require passport control during exit and I was thinking I may be doubted of visa shopping next time I apply for Lithuanian visa. Is it ok to proceed like this?

By the way, this is perfectly acceptable. When I applied visa, I submitted that I am landing at frankfurt, rather than prague, as the price was cheaper (I didn't say this). They didn't even ask why.


I was thinking I may be doubted of visa shopping next time I apply for Lithuanian visa.

To show that you complied with the itinerary you submitted in your visa application, you can keep your boarding passes (or images if they are mobile boarding passes) showing that you did in fact fly from Vienna to Vilnius.  You can also keep rail tickets, taxi receipts, and so on, along with receipts for any hotel or other paid accommodation, restaurant meals, or other paid activities or services.
The chance of this being needed or even useful is very small, but it should at least give you some peace of mind.

Yes this is exactly the way the Schengen area is supposed to work. There are some scenarios where questions can arise but I doubt the border guards in Vienna or the Lithuanian consulate will be concerned at all in this case as there aren't many flights from Armenia to Western Europe and Vienna is a logical layover.
